# rsync only filenames

Tags: linux, sync, rsync

Is it possible, to **only** rsync the filenames? I have a storage box and want the filenames (and their paths) added to another box. I'm currently creating each file with `touch` (they'll be created with a 0 byte size). It takes too long and was wondering if this could be automated with `rsync`.

If not, is there any other tool which allows this? Or would I need to code something custom?

Comment: Something like this? `find . -type d > direcotries` `find . -type f > files` and on remote `cat direcotries | xargs -I this mkdir this` `cat files | xargs -I this touch this`

Comment: Why create empty files?  What's the point of having so many empty files?

Comment: @unforgettableid The empty files are simple `.iso` files, which are needed for the SolusVM control panel on the master. However I want one central repo for the ISO's, which will then be rsynced to all the noded while the master only has empty files (needed for control panel to function).

Comment: @Devator: OK, so you say the actual ISOs are stored in a directory on an ISO-storage PC. Well, perhaps you could use file-sharing software to mount that directory on the master PC. Would that eliminate your need to periodically sync the filenames? If not, why not?

Comment: @unforgettableid It actually might yes, I'll look into that. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Devator:  You're welcome.  Please let me know how it works out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your aim is to create empy files, than a template may be created like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=$1 # original structure
TMPL=$2  # where to create empty files
[[ -d $FILES ]] || exit 1
[[ -d $TMPL ]] || mkdir -p $TMPL || exit 1

cd $TMPL
find "$FILES" -type d -printf "$TMPL%p\0" | sort -z |xargs -0 -L 1000 mkdir -p
find "$FILES" -type f -printf "$TMPL%p\0" | xargs -0 -L 1000 touch
```

This creates the directory of every file from the original tree and touches the files in the folders created under TMPL.

After creating a "mirrored" folder with only empty files, it can be rsynced to any host like any other folder:

```
rsync -av -e 'ssh -p 22 -l username' \
    /template/structure remotehost:/backup/templates/
```

The -e option is optional if the username is the same on both hosts and if sshd runs on the default port. Pay attention to what happens when you specify a trailing slash on both or either of the from and to parts. It is significant. The remotehost parameter, may be an ip address instead of an alias.

Comment: @Devator have a look at my revised answer

Comment: Thanks, going to use this :) Figured it already regarding rsyncing the empty folder. Cheers!

Comment: If you additionally want to include symlinks add the following line to the end of the script `find "$FILES" -type l -printf "ln -s %l $TMPL%p\0" | xargs -0 -L 1000 sh -c`

Comment: this example assumes you have gnu find and xargs. on mac os, use brew to get them.

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` itself doesn't seem to have an option to only create files. However, you could try various ways rather than using touch manually:

- rsync the directory tree, then run `find` on the root of that tree and `echo "" >` into each file
- use `find` to get a list of directory trees, then use `mkdir -p` on each element of that list (possibly reverse-sorting beforehand to minimise the number of syscalls) and then use `touch` on a similarly created list of files.

I would, however, go with the first option if the space is available, as it preserves permissions and access rights (given appropriate arguments to `rsync`).

Comment: Yes, I'd like to do the first one, but space is **the** problem. :(

Comment: Maybe running it only on parts of the directory tree at a time would solve that problem?

Comment: No, there's not enough space.